# Where does top get its CPU usage data from?

Tags: linux, performance, unix, top

I want to write some scripts that will measure the CPU use, but `top`'s output, while pleasant for the user, isn't really feasible for processing in a script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check `$ man proc`. `/proc` has a subdirectory for each pid on the system. Under each of those is a "stat" file, which includes CPU usage information for that specific pid.

Answer (score 0):

If you want information about CPU usage across a span of time, take a look at the [mpstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpstat) command.